# Jsoup converting unicode entites to html entities while parsing

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a String like below

```
String input="<div class="prov2Txt">(2)&#x00a0;&#x00a0;Notwithstanding anything in any other written law and notwithstanding the making of an oath or declaration of secrecy, a person shall not be guilty of an offence by reason of anything done by him for the purposes of section&#x00a0;6.</div>";
```

And I am parsing it using JSOUP then Jsoup removes All the Unicode entities(`&#x00a0`) to html entity.

```
Document d = Jsoup.parse(input);
d.outputSettings(new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
```

This code converts `&#x00a0` to its equvailent HTML entity.

Now  I want to retain all the unicode entities as it is  after parsing the input string.

Answer (score 1):

The xhtml escape mode may suit your needs:

```
d.outputSettings(new Document.OutputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml).prettyPrint(false));
```

It turns `&#x00a0` into `&#xa0;`.

Comment: I have tried all this.Dont work for me                 `document.outputSettings(new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
document.outputSettings(new Document.OutputSettings());
// Adjust escape mode
document.outputSettings().escapeMode();`

Comment: @vinaykaushik I don't see the sample code in the answer. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I have try this.

Comment: @vinaykaushik What is your JVM version, Jsoup version and Java locale?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Jsoup 1.9.1  Locale :      en-us;English (United States)